# Environment variables not found in console and composer

Tags: symfony, wamp, symfony-3.2

I set environment variables and removed parameters.yml file according to new recommended configuration.

In my local environment (WAMP), I set these in .htaccess file in the root of my project. The app is working, but Symfony console and composer can't find variables. I can't find why. Do you have an idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to set environment variables on the terminal. PHP CLI mode will not load instruction within `.htaccess`

```
export VARNAME="my value"
```

in your case with windows in `cmd` it will be:

```
set NEWVAR=SOMETHING
```

Comment: Actually, each time I close my IDE and WAMP, I have to set again all variables...